# Optimization of spark cluster configuration（ Low configuration virtual machine cluster）

Tags: apache-spark

When I use Spark's standalone mode to process a large number of datasets,the log said:

```
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl:70 - Lost executor 1 on : Executor heartbeat timed out after 381181 ms
```

I search the internet, they say I should set parameters with spark submit：

```
[hadoop@Master spark2.4.0]$ bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --conf spark.worker.timeout 10000000 --py-files id.py id.py --name id
```

Error message in log:

```
Error: Invalid argument to --conf: spark.worker.timeout
```

**Questions:**
How to set timeout parameter?

Thanks to meniluca's answer, I lost the symbols in instructions

After adjusting the timeout, the log displays

```
2019-12-05 19:42:27 WARN  Utils:87 - Suppressing exception in finally: broken pipe (Write failed)
java.net.SocketException:  broken pipe (Write failed)
2019-12-05 21:13:09 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
Exception in thread "serve-DataFrame" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException:  broken pipe (Write failed)
```

then,I change thessh，add ServerAliveInterval 60 while ~/.ssh/ config

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

the error stil exits, then I try to increase the driver memory, error still exists, and show that the connection is disconnected

```
[hadoop@Master spark2.4.0]$ bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --conf spark.worker.timeout=10000000 --driver-memory 1g --py-files id.py id.py --name id
```

```
2019-12-06 10:38:49 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 374
Exception in thread "serve-DataFrame" java.net.SocketException:  broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$serveIterator$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$serveIterator$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$6.apply(PythonRDD.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$6.apply(PythonRDD.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonServer$$anon$1.run(PythonRDD.scala:862)
2019-12-06 11:06:12 WARN  HeartbeatReceiver:66 - Removing executor 1 with no recent heartbeats: 149103 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
2019-12-06 11:06:12 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl:70 - Lost executor 1 on 219.226.109.129: Executor heartbeat timed out after 149103 ms
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Executor lost: 1 (epoch 6)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 WARN  HeartbeatReceiver:66 - Removing executor 0 with no recent heartbeats: 155761 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
2019-12-06 11:06:13 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl:70 - Lost executor 0 on 219.226.109.131: Executor heartbeat timed out after 155761 ms
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Requesting to kill executor(s) 1
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Removing block manager BlockManagerId(1, 219.226.109.129, 42501, None)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removed 1 successfully in removeExecutor
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Shuffle files lost for executor: 1 (epoch 6)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 1
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Host added was in lost list earlier: 219.226.109.129
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Executor lost: 0 (epoch 7)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@490228e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Removing block manager BlockManagerId(0, 219.226.109.131, 42164, None)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removed 0 successfully in removeExecutor
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Shuffle files lost for executor: 0 (epoch 7)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Host added was in lost list earlier: 219.226.109.131
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Stopped Spark web UI at http://Master:4040
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Registering block manager 219.226.109.129:42501 with 413.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, 219.226.109.129, 42501, None)
2019-12-06 11:06:13 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Registering block manager 219.226.109.131:42164 with 413.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 219.226.109.131, 42164, None)
2019-12-06 11:06:14 INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Shutting down all executors
2019-12-06 11:06:14 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asking each executor to shut down
2019-12-06 11:06:14 INFO  BlockManagerInfo:54 - Added broadcast_15_piece0 in memory on 219.226.109.129:42501 (size: 21.1 KB, free: 413.9 MB)
2019-12-06 11:06:15 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2019-12-06 11:06:15 INFO  BlockManagerInfo:54 - Added broadcast_15_piece0 in memory on 219.226.109.131:42164 (size: 21.1 KB, free: 413.9 MB)
2019-12-06 11:06:16 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2019-12-06 11:06:16 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2019-12-06 11:06:16 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2019-12-06 11:06:17 ERROR TransportResponseHandler:144 - Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from Master/219.226.109.130:7077 is closed
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e2a29bac-7277-4476-ad23-315a27e9ccf0
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/localPyFiles-dd95954c-2e77-41ca-969d-a201269f5b5b
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bcd56b4a-fb32-4b58-a1d5-71abc5218d32
2019-12-06 11:06:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e2a29bac-7277-4476-ad23-315a27e9ccf0/pyspark-d04b799f-a116-44d5-b6a5-811cc8c03743
```

**Question**

1. Is SSH related to broken pipe?
2. Is increasing driver memory helpful to this problem?
3. I see the configuration posts on the Internet, but they're are highly configured. Since I use my computer to built clusters on virtual machine,
   , the master has two cores , the slave has one core. How to adjust the configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
--conf spark.worker.timeout=10000000
```

you are missing the equal character between the configuration name and value.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still have problems about configuration, I re-edit the question ,  Can you have a look again?

Comment: please try to start a pyspark shell with the following command: ``bin/pyspark --master spark://master:7077 --conf spark.worker.timeout=10000000 --driver-memory 1g``. If this works it means the problem is in your python file. Please share the content of that file. Besides ``--name`` should go before your id.py and it's not necessary to use ``--py-files`` if id.py contains the main of your program.

Answer (score 0):

java.net.SocketException:  broken pipe (Write failed) occurs when something is wrong with the access port. 
I suggest you to change the master which is at port 8080. The port can be changed either in the configuration file or via command-line options.

```
sbin/start-master.sh
```

Same can be tried with worker node as well if the above does not fix issue.
To see which ports are being used you can use :

```
sudo netstat -ltup
```